# How to show the number of days ago people joined a Discord server using discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a user info command that will show how many days ago people joined or created a Discord server. I saw in many servers that it shows "n" number of days ago and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the member object either using [fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#discord.Client.fetch_user) or [message author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_user#message).

I used message author in this example using `discord.ext.commands`.

```py
import datetime as dt

@bot.command()
async def joined(ctx):
    duration = dt.datetime.now() - ctx.author.joined_at 

    hours, remainder = divmod(int(duration .total_seconds()), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)

    await ctx.send(f"Joined before {days}d, {hours}h, {minutes}m, {seconds}s")
```

If you want to use fetch_user replace `ctx.author` above with user

```py
user = bot.fetch_user(ID_HERE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`member.joined_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at)

```py
mem_join = member.joined_at
guild_create = guild.created_at
join_days = (mem_join - guild_create).days
#Example: 314 days
```