# discord.py how to get info when member registered on discord, and joined server

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

i want to create command to see when that person who write command registered on discord and when he joined my server, i tryed `author.joined_at` and `author.created_at` but this doesn't work tried to find on API reference too, but no results

**when i use this code bot just not replying, i don't know the problem, when i replace funcions everything work, so i think(maybe i am wrong) that problem in incorrect using of functions or  me of them, that's why i asked**

```
@client.command( aliases = ['uinfo'])

async def userinfo( ctx ):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = f'{ ctx.author } | { ctx.author.display_name }', color = discord.Color.green(), description = f'{ctx.author.id} |' )
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Joined server', value = f'{ author.joined_at }' )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Joined discord', value = f'{author.created_at}' )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? There's no other way of getting when a user joined a guild/created his account.

Comment: there is code in question, code work without errors, but when i write command nothing happens

Comment: How is that related to the title of your question then? It's confusing, please edit your question.

Comment: you can see 2 pre-last lines, problems that this 2 functions doesn't work in this code

Comment: I really doubt that's the problem

Comment: i don't know the problem, when i replace funcions everything work, so i think(maybe i am wrong) that problem in incorrect using of functions, that's why i asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the date the user joined the server, I use this code:

```
ctx.author.joined_at.strftime(date_format)
```

And for the date of the user's registration, I use this:

```
ctx.author.created_at.strftime(date_format)
```

This is explained [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20created_at#discord.User.created_at).

"Date format" is a variable I created so that the date and time will be easy to understand, for example, this is mine:

```
date_format = "%a, %b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p"
```

I hope you find this useful!

Comment: yes, this works, thanks to you, but if i want to show like 2 years ago, i should today time - time person joined? can you pls show code like example of this

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328695/how-to-show-the-number-of-days-ago-people-joined-a-discord-server-using-discord) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
    async def whois(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
         if user is None:
             user = ctx.author      
         date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
         embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFF0000, description=user.mention)
         embed.set_author(name=str(user), icon_url=user.avatar_url)
         embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
         embed.add_field(name="Joined Server", value=user.joined_at.strftime(date_format), inline=False)
         members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m: m.joined_at)
         embed.add_field(name="Join Position", value=str(members.index(user)+1), inline=False)
         embed.add_field(name="Joined Discord", value=user.created_at.strftime(date_format), inline=False)
         if len(user.roles) > 1:
             role_string = ' '.join([r.mention for r in user.roles][1:])
             embed.add_field(name="Roles [{}]".format(len(user.roles)-1), value=role_string, inline=False)
         embed.set_footer(text='ID: ' + str(user.id))
         return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: make sure to remove {self}, unless you are using a cog

Comment: nope, just bot doesn't responding to `whois` command

Comment: line 94
    members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m: m.joined_at)
                                                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\ds\bot.py"]
[dir: D:\ds]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common